# SQL SUM with condition / Invalid column name 'SUM'

Tags: sql, sum

I'm trying to make a sum of the variable value/valeur with some conditions but I obtain this error: Invalid column name 'SUM'.

```
SELECT SUM[value/valeur] 
FROM [dbo].[tmp_norm_can]
WHERE [state/etat] = '1000' 
  AND [geo/geo] = '1' 
  AND [country/pays] != '999'
```

I attached an image of the database

Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/340TZ.png)

Comment: `sum()` needs parentheses around its parameters, not brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you!

The code that worked was:
`SELECT SUM(CAST([value/valeur] AS NUMERIC)) AS "TOTAL",  [year/annee]  FROM [dbo].[tmp_norm_can] WHERE [state/etat] = '1000' AND [geo/geo] = '1' AND [country/pays] != '999'`

Answer (score 2):

`sum` is a function, you need to pass its argument in parentheses:

```
SELECT SUM([value/valeur])
FROM [dbo].[tmp_norm_can]
WHERE [state/etat] = '1000' 
  AND [geo/geo] = '1'
  AND [country/pays] != '999'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try aliasing your column with a name different than "SUM".

Comment: Where is a column aliased?

Comment: The error OP got was: Invalid column name: "SUM", which I infered to mean that they were using some other software that inferred the column name. Looking back, they just missed the parens to wrap the SUM.